# How to continue a "forest" using multiple columns (minipages)

Tags: minipage, forest, columnbreak

I'm using a `forest` to illustrate a folder structure. Due to the length of the tree I would like to split it into two "columns". For this I'm using two minipages.

To demonstrate that both "subtrees" share the same root, I would like to continue the root of the first (left) minipage till the end.

Is this possible?

Image below shows the current tree in black and the line that I'm talking about in red:
[image]

here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{forest}
  for tree={
    font=\normalfont,
    grow'=0,
    child anchor=west,
    parent anchor=south,
    anchor=west,
    calign=first,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- node[fill,inner sep=1.25pt] {} (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      if n=1
        {insert before={[,phantom]}}
        {}
    },
    fit=band,
    before computing xy={l=15pt},
  }
[root
  [\faFolderOpenO ~One
    [\faFolderOpenO ~OneOne]
    [\faFolderOpenO ~OneTwo
      [\faFolderOpenO ~OneTwoOne]
      [\faFolderOpenO ~OneTwoTwo]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{minipage}% 
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
 \begin{forest}
  for tree={
    font=\normalfont,
    grow'=0,
    child anchor=west,
    parent anchor=south,
    anchor=west,
    calign=first,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.south west) +(7.5pt,0) |- node[fill,inner sep=1.25pt] {} (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      if n=1
        {insert before={[,phantom]}}
        {}
    },
    fit=band,
    before computing xy={l=15pt},
  }
[
  [\faFolderOpenO ~Two
    [\faFolderOpenO ~TwoOne]
  ]
  [\faFolderOpenO ~Three
    [\faFolderOpenO ~ThreeOne]
  ]
  [\faFolderOpenO ~Four]
]
\end{forest}
\end{minipage}

\caption{Captiontext}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you wedded to `minipage`s? Note that this is much easier with the `edges` library.

Comment: @cfr nope I just thought its the simplest approach (just need to have a combined caption for both subforests)

Comment: Actually, it probably is simplest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ways of having Forest split the tree. However, in this case `minipage`s are probably the simplest strategy, as you say.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\forestset{%
  declare boolean register={my dir tree cont},
  my dir tree cont=false,
  my dir tree/.style={
    for tree={
      grow'=0,
      folder,
      edge label={node [fill, inner sep=1.25pt, midway] {} },
    },
    delay={
      for nodewalk={
        if my dir tree cont={fake=r}{r},
        descendants
      }{content/.wrap value={\faFolderOpenO ~##1}},
      if my dir tree cont={}{
        tikz+={
          \draw (!r.parent anchor |- !r1.child anchor) ++(\foresteregister{folder indent},0) coordinate (a) -- (current bounding box.south -| a) node [below, font=\footnotesize, gray] {cont.};
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{forest}
    my dir tree
    [root
      [One
        [OneOne]
        [OneTwo
          [OneTwoOne]
          [OneTwoTwo]
        ]
      ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{minipage}% 
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{forest}
    my dir tree,
    my dir tree cont,
    [
      [Two
        [TwoOne]
      ]
      [Three
        [ThreeOne]
      ]
      [Four]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: split <code>forest</code> trees]